# error: ‘ArucoDetector’ is not a member of ‘cv::aruco’

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, ros, aruco

I am building a program in ROS using OpenCV C++ to detect ArUco codes.My OpenCV version is 4.2.
I've included the header file:
 `#include <opencv2/aruco.hpp>.`
And called the function：
`cv::aruco::ArucoDetector detector(dictionary, detectorParams);`

While writing this line of code, vscode can provide automatic completion and allow me to navigate to the definition file of this function.BUT when I compile, an error occurs.

`error: ‘ArucoDetector’ is not a member of ‘cv::aruco’`

How can I resolve this issue? What caused this problem?

My code is as follows.

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/aruco.hpp>


//#include <opencv2/objdetect/aruco_detector.hpp>

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/Image.h"
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>


static const std::string OPENCV_WINDOW = "Image window";

class ImageConverter
{
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
    image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_;
public:
    ImageConverter()
    : it_(nh_)
    {
        // Subscrive to input video feed and publish output video feed
        image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/robot/camera/image", 1,&ImageConverter::imageCb, this);
        cv::namedWindow(OPENCV_WINDOW);
    }
     ~ImageConverter()
    {
        cv::destroyWindow(OPENCV_WINDOW);
    }
 
    void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
    {
        cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
        try
        {
            cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
        }
        catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
        {
            ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
            return;
        }

        cv::Mat img =  cv_ptr->image;
        cv::Mat img_copy = img.clone();
        cv::Mat img_gray;
        //cv::imshow("test_opencv", img);
        cv::cvtColor(img, img_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        cv::aruco::DetectorParameters detectorParams = cv::aruco::DetectorParameters();
        cv::aruco::Dictionary dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_6X6_250);
        cv::aruco::ArucoDetector detector(dictionary, detectorParams);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "opencv_test");
    ImageConverter ic;
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is as follows.

```
/home/zhilinxu/catkin_ws_webots/src/vis_ser_demo01/src/main.cpp: In member function ‘void ImageConverter::imageCb(const ImageConstPtr&)’:
/home/zhilinxu/catkin_ws_webots/src/vis_ser_demo01/src/main.cpp:94:20: error: ‘ArucoDetector’ is not a member of ‘cv::aruco’
   94 |         cv::aruco::ArucoDetector detector(dictionary, detectorParams);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [vis_ser_demo01/CMakeFiles/demo01.dir/build.make:63: vis_ser_demo01/CMakeFiles/demo01.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:902: vis_ser_demo01/CMakeFiles/demo01.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j20 -l20" failed
```

It seems that `cv::aruco::ArucoDetector` is defined in the header file `opencv2/objdetect/aruco_detector.hpp`, which is already included in `opencv2/aruco.hpp`. When attempting to directly include `opencv2/objdetect/aruco_detector.hpp` in my code, I encountered redefinition errors during compilation.

In my code, both `cv::aruco::DetectorParameters` and `cv::aruco::Dictionary` are from `opencv2/objdetect/aruco_detector.hpp`, yet they compile fine. It's quite odd.

Comment: Do you have two different OpenCV versions installed in your system? One you installed manually, and another that was installed with ROS? There can be chance the VSCode is using 4.2, and the one gets complied with catkin_make uses another.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem (though I was using cv 4.5), and found that the api seems to have changed

Instead of this (from the opencv example):

```
cv::aruco::DetectorParameters detectorParams = cv::aruco::DetectorParameters();
cv::aruco::Dictionary dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_6X6_250);

cv::aruco::ArucoDetector detector(dictionary, detectorParams);

detector.detectMarkers(inputImage, markerCorners, markerIds);
```

We end up with this:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::Dictionary> dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_6X6_250);
cv::aruco::detectMarkers(inputImage, dictionary, markerCorners, markerIds);
```

Notice the use of cv::Ptr for the dictionary, and the static function detectMarkers (no need to instantiate a detector)